# ASP Custom Routing with no parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller actions in my PartnerController, each with their own custom routing.

***Action 1***

```
public ActionResult GetCardWithShortCode(string voucherShortCode)
```

> routes.MapRoute(
>                   "GetCardWithShortcode",
>                   "partner/store/getcard/{voucherShortCode}",
>                   new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetCardWithShortCode" }
>                   );

***Action 2***

```
public ActionResult GetCard()
```

> routes.MapRoute(
>                   "GetCard",
>                   "partner/store/getcard",
>                   new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetCard"}
>                   );

The first routing works fine, but I just can't get the second one to work. Theoretically when I hit ../partner/store/getcard it should hit the second action?

Any Ideas?

Comment: post all of your routes in the exact order that they are added.

Comment: change the sequence.. add second at the top and try it.. it should be most specific to least specific.

Comment: I see no problem with this (which MVC ?). Works here (MVC4). As long as voucherShortCode is not optional, it should work.
What do you mean with "can't get the second one to work" 404 ? caught by another Controller/action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have following order while adding route

```
routes.MapRoute( "GetCard", "partner/store/getcard", new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetCard"} );


routes.MapRoute( "GetCardWithShortcode", "partner/store/getcard/{voucherShortCode}", new { controller = "Partner", action = "GetCardWithShortCode" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The second action is not hit because the first one is called instead with {voucherShortCode} null

What you can do is use just one route and do:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(voucherShortCode))
    return RedirectToAction("GetCard")
```

Then you don't need two routes.

Comment: not a gud method @tucaz :) it should work with routing itself

Comment: It should, indeed, but you can save one route if you do like this :)

Comment: yeah that's true, we can avoid such specific route until they are not serving more than 1 request